# How to convert Active control into text box type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I  have a function like this:

```
public static void NewFunction (TextBox txtOne)
{
  //Do Something with txtOne
}
```

Now I want to pass the current Active text box to txtOne. I tried to call this as

```
NewFunction(ActiveControl.Name)
```

But this says invalid arguments. Please someone can help me to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there but you made a mistake.
When you call your method you need to pass the control, not its name

```
NewFunction(ActiveControl)
```

Now, if you have more than one controls, more than one type of control, you may run in to problem. So, for this, you should do the following - make parameter of type `Control` and add this code

```
public static void NewFunction (Control ctrl)
{
    TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        //Do Something with txtOne
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `ActiveControl.Name` property is type of `string`. You should convert `ActiveControl` to value of `TextBox` type and pass this value to your function.
Here is example:

```
var textBox = ActiveControl as TextBox;

if (textBox != null)
   NewFunction(textBox);
```